# Google Maps API: Is there any way to show POI markers (establishments) without making them clickable and having the info window pop out?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

[Disable point-of-interest information window using Google Maps API v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7478069/google-map-api-v3-disable-point-of-interest-info-window)

This question shows the problem of having clickable establishments (POIs) on your map and how to remove them.... but is there any way to keep the POIs but disable the info windows (or even better, perform a custom action, such as going to your own page that refers to that business)?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I found a dirty workaround, look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8361698/684229

Comment: yikes! that is dirty - but thanks! it's too bad google doesn't seem to allow this - it really screws up an app when you have random info windows popping up when people are trying to click around (and still show local businesses).

Answer (score 2):

Short answer, given the current Google Maps API: No. I wish they'd change this!